# Plugging in a USB mouse disconnects the PS/2 one

Tags: usb, hid, keypad

I always used PS/2 KB and Mouse and a USB KeyPad (Genius ErgoMedia 500 Gaming Explorer) to play some games, MMORPG, FPS, etc.

I have a USB mouse that has 4 extra buttons, and I need more.  If I plug in the USB mouse and disconnect the PS/2, everything is okay until I touch the mouse. If I do so, the ErgoMedia goes off, then on, then I move the mouse or press a button and it happens all over again.

Yesterday, I bought a new mouse that I liked, also a USB mouse (NPlay with macros and all that stuff, 3600 DPI) I was hoping that the problem was only with the other mouse, but no.. It does the exact same thing, ErgoMedia keeps disconecting and conecting every time I touch the mouse.

What I already did:

- Updated drivers of both mouses
- Updated drivers of ErgoMedia (no specific drivers(Windows based))
- Updated drivers of MB Chipset (Actualy no, cause it was up to date allready)
- Tried other USB Ports (4 Ports back, 4 Ports Front and even 1 Port in 16 card slot device)
- Disabled the "Allows Windows to shut down the energy, etc." thing in Device Setings.
- Looked up in the Device Setings only apear a problem on the ergomedia (Human interface Device) when I move the damned mouse
- Used Everest to read the behavior, everything normal, excepts the disconecting thing, but no errors.
- Ruled out the power suply, only the ErgoMedia and the mouse are in the USBs, and I already disable the 16 card reader with one USB slot to see.
- Cleaned the IRQ registry.

Machine: Acer M3641 Core2Quad 64x Based OS Vista 64b 4GbRAM HD Audio and Graphics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, connect a usb hub to the PC and then connect the new mouse to the usb hub, see if the strange behavior stops.

Comment: i went crazy trying that cause it was something that i didn´t tryit, but, same problem, my uncle even borou me a charged HUB but same thing again.. What i hate most is one friend from work and my uncle have the exact same ErgoMedia and now the exact same mouse. One is using Window 7 other Vista 64b like me.. The difrences i thing is the stupid microsoft upgrades, or maybe something that i instaled, i don´t know. Im starting to give up.. I try in my laptop, an HP whit Vista 32B and in 2 sec it´s fine. But tankyou very mutch for ur concern, apreciated a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Heres an idea; Get a USB to PS/2 adapter, such as [This One.](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/searchtools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=2095162&SRCCODE=CANWGOOCAPLA&cm_mmc_o=mH4CjC7BBTkwCjCECjCE&gclid=Cj0KEQjwxZieBRDegZuj9rzLt_ABEiQASqRd-iNNSQ-QfVSf3wmQJfpoNMR5zimyCQte_pDCPZEJW-AaAtI88P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds) This will let the PS\2 mouse funcion as a USB mouse. As long as your computer will let you have more than one USB mice connected at a time, then this will work.